# Again, Class not found

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxelib, stablexui

When I have upgraded stablexui to the last version, I first removed it:

```
haxelib remove stablexui
```

then installed the last version:

```
haxelib install stablexui
```

then, when I try to compile, I get this error:

> src/com/clientside/Icon.hx:3: characters 7-30 : Class not found :
>   ru.stablex.ui.UIBuilder Build halted with errors (haxelib.exe).

Although its installed, here is my haxelib list:

```
actuate: [1.7.0]
dcaclab_types: [1.0]
hscript: [2.0.1]
hxlibc: [1.0.0]
hxtools: [1.1.6]
openfl: [1.1.1]
openfl-html5-dom: [1.1.1]
openfl-native: [1.1.4]
openfl-samples: [1.1.0]
rox-i18n: [1.0.0]
stablexui: [1.0.15]
swf: [1.1.1]
```

Any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to update haxelib itself. Try `haxelib selfupdate` (and then haxe update.hxml). In version 3.1.0 we introduced the possibility to put a library's classpath into a subfolder of the package and many libraries use that. Unfortunately, the Haxe installer still comes with haxelib 3.0.0.

Comment: I've got an answer from the lib author here http://www.openfl.org/community/general-discussion/class-not-found/ is seems that he has a higher version of haxelib, I will try selfupdate, thanks